# How do you choose the initial view for a flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4.5, mate, mate-flex-framework

I want to load an initial component to be displayed in my flex app, depending on whether a value in the `SharedObject` is set (first launch). How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               applicationComplete="onApplicationComplete()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function onApplicationComplete():void
            {
                var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal('something');
                // add conditionals here
                    addElement(new SomeView());
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Or with States:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               applicationComplete="onApplicationComplete()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function onApplicationComplete():void
            {
                var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal('something');
                // add conditionals here
                    this.currentState = 'someview2';
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        </s:State name="someview" />
        </s:State name="someview2" />
        </s:State name="someview3" />
    </s:states>

    <local:SomeView includeIn="someview" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <local:SomeView2 includeIn="someview2" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <local:SomeView3 includeIn="someview3" width="100%" height="100%" />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I’m sorry but I thought it had something to do with the viewStack. Is this good practice?

Comment: You could use ViewStack if you wanted to but I would use states instead since ViewStack is getting deprecated. Modified answer.

Comment: Deprecated? Could you please elaborate on that? ViewStacks are an entire chapter of the Flex book I bought.

Comment: ViewStacks are Flex 3 (mx package), we are now in Flex 4 (Spark) and there has been a *major* fix in states for Flex 4.  Hence, there's no need to use ViewStack, just use states.  I think your book might be a tad old and aiming for Flex 3, but it's still not a bad idea to learn about deffered instantiation.